# O que significa "tchiiiiii" em português de Portugal?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, gíria

Algumas vezes já vi colegas portugueses escreverem "*tchiiiiii*". Imagino que seja uma gíria/calão ou algo do tipo. O que significa essa palavra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Embora seja mais frequente dizer *"xi"* ou *"chi"*, essa é considerada uma interjeição com significado bastante semelhante às anteriores, e é usada em caso de admiração e/ou desagrado perante um acontecimento ou situação. [Este PDF](http://www.teiaportuguesa.com/manual/unidade16sentimentos/jginterjeicoes1.pdf) tem uma lista interessante de interjeições.

> -- Bati com o meu carro, um dos faróis partiu-se.
>
> -- Tchiii, isso vai sair caro!

Comment: Então, o mesmo que vixe.